# Flutter: the terminal not responding and does not view the results

Tags: flutter, cmd, terminal, command, runtime-error

The terminal not responding and does not view the results on VScode and AndroidS,
please help me ☺.
this is my terminal
[image]

Comment: once try doing close and open

FYI `flutter clear` is not a correct command. `flutter clean` is the correct command.

Comment: I typed flutter clear quickly so I didn't notice it, but my terminal doesn't work on any command.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried restarting the session CTRL+Maiusc+T (or right click).
This will restart the terminal and hopefully you will be able to execute commands.

Also, try to close the session and restart it manually if the first option doesn't work.
Hope it works!

Comment: Hello bro, can you explain to me what is a Maiusc button?

Comment: I did ctrl +shift +p and then Reload Window, but it did not solve the problem, I also closed vscode and reopened it, and even shut down the computer as well and the problem did not solve

Comment: My bad! Forgot that in English is called Shift! Anyway did you try the solution that @nagendra nag has written?

Comment: Yes, I did, but that didn't work either.
Actually, I want to solve my main problem, which is that I can't run my code without using terminal commands.

this is main problem on StackOverflow:
" Flutter : I had this error suddenly, when I wanted to connect my phone to my project(Run and Debug) "